# Check which fragment is selected Android

Tags: android, if-statement, android-fragments

I have a navigation view for which I use this switch to change my fragment depending on the item selected :

```
Fragment fragment = null;
String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

switch (viewId) {
    case R.id.nav_random:
        fragment = new Random();
        title = "RANDOM";

        break;
    case R.id.nav_podium:
        fragment = new Podium();
        title = "PODIUM";
        break;
    case R.id.nav_sport:
        fragment = new Sport();
        title = "SPORT";
        break;
    case R.id.nav_videogames:
        fragment = new Games();
        title = "GAMES";
        break;
    case R.id.nav_socialnetwork:
        fragment = new SocialNetwork();
        title = "SOCIAL NETWORKS";
        break;
    case R.id.nav_heart:
        fragment = new Heart();
        title = "FAVORITES";
        break;

}
```

I want to check if the fragment selected is "Podium" or whichever else, how can I do that?
I have tried something like `if fragment == new Podium()` or `if fragment == Podium` but I can't figure out how to check which fragment is selected and then displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure what use you have for this because you never use the Fragment variable, but you can use [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) to check which type of object a variable is.

```
if (fragment instanceof Podium) {
  // it's a Podium
}
```

Alternatively, you could store all `new Fragment()` instances in a `List<Fragment>`, then just use an integer value to know which one is selected.

Just go through your switch-case, for example, like so

```
case R.id.nav_random:
    fragment = new Random();
    title = "RANDOM";
    position = 0;
    break;
case R.id.nav_podium:
    fragment = new Podium();
    title = "PODIUM";
    position = 1;
    break;
```

Then `fragmentList.get(position)` is always the selected one.

Comment: Thanks it's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Another viable solution would be compare it by its TAG as when you added or replaced it with the fragmentManager, I supose you added a tag in the fragment transaction:

```
fragment.getTag().equals(Random.TAG)
```

That statement requires you to have the TAG as a constant:

```
public class Random extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = "RANDOMFRAG";
}
```